# converting text file to pdf

Tags: java, jsp, pdf, itext7

I want to convert text file to a pdf document in a Java web application in a JSP. I am trying to do it using iText library. I have included external library itextpdf-7 jar files into my project but still, these red lines are shown. Please help out!

[image: enter image description]

Comment: try clean build.

Comment: You say "I have included external library itextpdf-**7** jar files into my project", but your code contains **com.lowagie**. Lowagie is my name, and I am the creator of the **com.lowagie** classes. Those classes are iText **2** classes; they no longer exist in iText **7**. My guess is that one of your main classes is the fact that you mix iText 2 and iText 7. Those versions are incompatible with each other. There is little more anyone can say, are you don't show any of your iText-related code. You read a file into a `StringBuffer`, but what are you doing with the `StringBuffer`?

Comment: Aside from what I wrote in my previous comment, I have closed the question as a duplicate. You are trying to create a binary file (PDFs are binary files) using JSP. JSP is not meant to create binary files. With JSP, you can create text-based content such as HTML files, but JSP was never meant to create binary files such as PDFs. One major error I see in your code is the occurrence of white space between every `%>` and `<%`. That white space corrupts the binary file you want to send to the `OutputStream`. Using JSP to create PDF is a bad design choice.

Comment: The "red lines" on the other hand are caused by the fact that you don't have the right jars in your CLASSPATH. That's a simple configuration problem. However, even if you get that fixed, that doesn't solve the more general problem mentioned in my answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: I copied this code from the internet. Within a JSP file, I need to convert a text format file to pdf. I read some code snippets online and tried to implement them. But reading your comments above made me realise what was I doing. Can you please guide me how can I convert a text format file to pdf fomat within a jsp.

Comment: You copied this code from the internet. Give the url where you got it from, so we can contact the author of that code, so they can correct it.

Comment: *Can you please guide me how can I convert a text format file to pdf fomat within a jsp.* I could, but I shouldn't, so I won't. As you could read in my comment: **JSP should not be used to create binary content.** Drop the idea of using JSP. Use a Servlet instead. Any JSP file is compiled to a Servlet anyway, so don't say "but I can't use servlets." If you use JSP, you *are* using servlets under the hood. If you say you can't use servlets, that would mean that you can't use JSP either.